# Time in DB compared to current time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a couple of stores that I'd like to display if they're open or not.

The issue is that I have my current time.

```
Time.current
=> Sat, 11 Jun 2016 11:57:41 CEST +02:00
```

and then if I for example take out the `open_at` for a store I get:

```
2000-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
```

so what I have now is:

```
  def current_business_hour(current_time: Time.current)
    business_hours.where('week_day = ? AND open_at <= ? AND close_at >= ?',
                         current_time.wday, current_time, current_time).first
  end
```

and then I check if a current_business_hour is present. However this is calculating it wrong by what seems like two hours. The open_at and close_at should be within the time zone of `Time.current`.

Comment: How do you know that it "calculates the time wrong"? Normally, Rails stores times in UTC in the DB, so I'd expect you'll see times 2 hours "backwards" in the SQL queries, as you are in the CEST time zone.

Comment: I use it to allow users to visit the store, and when the clock strikes 2PM and I've set open_at to 2PM it's not open, however 2 hours later it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails, dates and times are normally **saved in UTC in the database** and Rails automatically **converts the times to/from the local time zone** when working with the record.

However, for pure `time` type columns, Rails doesn't do such automatic conversion if the time is specified as a string only. It **must be specified as a `Time` object** instead, which includes the local time zone.

So, for example, if you wanted to store the `open_at` time as `14:00` local time, you should not set the attribute with a plain string, because it will be saved to the db verbatim, not converted to UTC:

```
business_hour.open_at = '14:00'
business_hour.save
# => UPDATE `business_hours` SET `open_at` = '2000-01-01 14:00:00.000000', `updated_at` = '2016-06-11 15:32:14' WHERE `business_hours`.`id` = 1

business_hour.open_at
# => 2000-01-01 14:00:00 UTC
```

When Rails reads such record back, it indeed thinks it's '14:00' UTC, which is off by 2 hours in the CEST zone.

You should convert the time from string to a `Time` object instead, because it will contain the proper local time zone:

```
business_hour.open_at = Time.parse('14:00')
business_hour.save
# => UPDATE `business_hours` SET `open_at` = '2000-01-01 12:00:00.000000', `updated_at` = '2016-06-11 15:32:29' WHERE `business_hours`.`id` = 1

business_hour.open_at
# => 2016-06-11 14:00:00 +0200
```

Note that the column is now stored in UTC time. Now, you can safely compare the time columns with any other rails datetime objects, such as `Time.current`.